# Git over HTTP(s) as a transfer protocol

Tags: git

I was looking at the git documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) and it mentions that git supports HTTP(s). I'm curious about whether git does any kind of certificate validation when pushing/cloning codebases over HTTPS. If so, could someone point me to the code snippet where this happens?

Comment: Are you looking for where this happens in the git source code?

Comment: Found it -- unless I'm very mistaken, certificate validation is performed by libcurl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the git client does perform certificate validation. You can disable validation using this command:

```
git config ––global http.sslVerify false
```

Try checking the `http.sslVerify` documentation.

[Check here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/http.c#L254) for where it's called.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the following defined here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

http.sslVerify 
Whether to verify the SSL certificate when fetching or pushing over HTTPS. Can be overridden by the GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY environment variable.